# A MATLAB function and class have the same name. How can I handle it?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, object, overloading

So simple question, I have a MATLAB class that I made names "Cat". However there already exists a stand-alone function called "Cat" elsewhere in the same directory. Is there a way to make MATLAB use the class "Cat" and not the *function* "Cat"?

I could start renaming everything, but I would rather not do that, so I am wondering if there is a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: MATLAB resolves function/class calls based on the [MATLAB search path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/search-path.html) (according to documented rules). So if your class comes first before the other function, it will be found and called instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical workaround, which allows to use both `Cat`

Matlab uses the `Cat` which is first on the path. Modifying this within execution will be very difficult to understand and debug.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, what do you mean "first in the path" though? FYI for my case, the CAT function is in a directory, and the CAT class is within a sub-directory of that...

Comment: Go to File -> Set Path (or, for versions 2012b and later, serch this option somewhere), insert the sub-directory name, and push it up over the directory with the function `cat`.